# kiosk mode 1 in linked table cell displays as kiosk = tv

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana 5.3.1. I have a table panel in my dashboard. One of the cells links to another dashboard, URL looks like this:

http://localhost:8001/d/W0lzxmbmz/single-vehicle-stats?refresh=1s&orgId=1&var-vehicleid=$__cell&kiosk=1

However, When the second dashboard opens in a new tab, it looks more like kiosk=tv.

Answer (score 0):

Use &kiosk instead of &kiosk=1

Oddly when you cycle through view modes, the URL show kiosk=1 for kiosk mode...